# Blazor.Server.js 404

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor server app that is being embedded into a Shopify site through ["App Proxy"](https://shopify.dev/apps/online-store/app-proxies?locale=en)

The problem is that the site is unable to find the _framework/blazor.server.js file as it is looking for it at the Shopify site location and not were the Blazor server is hosted.
[image]

I have tried using `app.UsePathBase("/AppName");` in Program.cs
and read these articles

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#publish-the-app

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-7.0